# How to install nvm offline on Linux

Tags: linux, installation, nvm

I need to install nvm on a Linux server without Internet and without sudo privilege, but I can transfer any file to this offline server. I tried to use package from https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm, but when I tried `sh install.sh`, it reports `unable to access https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm.git/`. Is there a way to install nvm without Internet on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install NVM with internet connection, I haven't figured out how to install nvm locally, after that you also need to download whichever version of node you want from using a terminal that requires internet, and after those two steps, then you can change node version required.